# "Knowledgeable" needs an "about" in the end?

Tags: grammar

In the sentence:

> "There was **nothing he wasn't knowledgeable**, which made him a great hire."

Do you need to add an "about" in the end?

> "There was **nothing he wasn't knowledgeable about**, which made him a great hire."

In which situations do you add a preposition?

Answer (score 2):

The reason you need a preposition, in this case, is because there are two separate clauses:

> There was nothing
>
> He wasn't knowledgeable

***There*** is the subject of the sentence in this case, and ***nothing*** is the object that's being modified, so it needs to be connected to the clause "he wasn't knowledgeable" with a preposition.

You could rephrase it as:

> There was nothing **about which** he wasn't knowledgeable.

But generally speaking, there is nothing about "knowledgeable" that implies that it requires a preposition.  It would be fine to simply say

> He wasn't knowledgeable.

Answer (score 1):

A person can be knowledgeable.
A person can be knowledgeable about something.

Comment: In this case, it's "there was no subject he wasn't knowledgeable about"... What you're saying is that in this case, we need to add "about"?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.